# Notice: Array to string conversion in table insertion

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to store the ID value from another table and im getting

Notice: Array to string conversion

at line

```
$sql2 = "Insert into relations (id, className) values ($result,'$_POST[className]')";
```

This is my  code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select objectID from objects where objectName = '$_POST[relations]'");


if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysqli_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
var_dump($result);

$sql = "Insert into classes (className) values ('$_POST[className]')";
$sql2 = "Insert into relations (id, className) values ($result,'$_POST[className]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
print_r($_POST)
```

My debug outputs as:

```
array(1) { ["objectID"]=> string(1) "2" } 
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\matcher\insertclass.php on line 16
Error: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
```

Comment: If you have any smart comments about how this code is not good or is vulnerable, keep it to urself. thanks I already know this, Im only trying to get to a small goal. thanks :D

Comment: try "Insert into classes (className) values ('" . $_POST['className'] . "')";

Comment: @zsolt: that does absolutely NOTHING. `$x = "a$b"` is exactly the same as `$x = "a" . $b`.

Comment: @marc sure, but I was not sure about quoting array keys when parsed in double quotes strings. since your example does not consider that constellation, it remains valid to at least check this out. (Right now I can't test myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think $result is a array

```
$result['objectID'] => "2"
```

Use $result['objectID'] in place of $result

```
$sql2 = "Insert into relations (id, className) values ($result['objectID'],'$_POST[className]')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
...
$sql2 = "Insert into relations (id, className) values ($result,'$_POST[className]')";
                                                       ^^^^^^^
```

mysqli_fetch_assoc returns an array, which you then directly stuff into another string.

Comment: Better eyes than mine took the prize. And I was looking ever so close. Kudos! :)

Answer (score 0):

What does var_dump($_POST['className']) yield right before that query? Also, $_POST[className] should probably not parse at all, as it might think 'className' is a constant. Try {$_POST['className']} in the query instead.

Comment: var_dump($_POST['className'])  yields string(5) "fasfa" array(1) { ["objectID"]=> string(1) "1" }